# ArrayAdapter with JSONArray data does not call getView()

Tags: android, json

I am making an app that gets some data from the net as JSON then it should be displayed in a list view.

So far I have a class that gets the data and works successfully and as intended and I then have a custom ArrayAdapter class. When I run my code with soem Log.d()'s in various places to check if the code is working, the app will open, download the JSON and then send it back to my activity, the data then gets sent to the array adapter successfully

(Test this by calling a field of the first JSONObject in the data that is sent to the adapter).

As far as I can tell, the problem is that the getView() method is not being called when it should.

Code:

```
try {

        listAdapter = new CropListAdapter(this, R.layout.crop_listitem,
                crops.getJSONArray("crops"));

        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // setUpViews();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Adapater:

```
public class CropListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<JSONArray> {

    Context context;
    JSONArray data;
    int layoutResourceId;
    CropHolder cropHolder;

    public CropListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, JSONArray data) {

        super(context, layoutResourceId);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.cropHolder = null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("Working", "works here 38");
        View row = convertView;

        JSONObject crop;
        try {
            Log.d("Pos", Integer.toString(pos));
            crop = (JSONObject) data.getJSONObject(pos);

            if (row == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                        .getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                cropHolder = new CropHolder();
                cropHolder.tvCropId = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvCropId);
                cropHolder.tvCropName = (TextView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvCropName);
                cropHolder.ivCropImage = (ImageView) row
                        .findViewById(R.id.ivCropImage);

                row.setTag(cropHolder);

            } else {

                cropHolder = (CropHolder) row.getTag();

            }

            cropHolder.tvCropId.setText(crop.getString("crop_id"));
            cropHolder.tvCropName.setText(crop.getString("name"));
            Log.d("Item", "creating item " + crop.getString("name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return row;
    }

    static class CropHolder {

        TextView tvCropName;
        ImageView ivCropImage;
        TextView tvCropId;

    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion about implementation, you may wish to convert your JSON into a native object as intermediate data should you ever switch your web service from JSON to XML (or anything else). Just my 2¢.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If think that you should override `BaseAdapter`  in this case. By the way, if you want `getView()` to get called you have to override `getCount()` and let it returns `data. length()`

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where did you override `getCount()` method , your list adapter is returning 0 as the number of elements in the list, you need to override it and return the number of elements in the JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly , it's not a good idea to do this "crops.getJSONArray("crops")" , seems to be , you are downloading your jsonArray with Synchronous call. If it's synchronous then app will crash on newer android versions. You have to do download tasks Asynchonously and when done you have to notify the adapter that data has been updated. It will refresh the list.
2. It's also a bad idea to parse json within GetView method , it will affect smooth scrolling of listview and make your app crash if you don't handle exceptions correctly. You should load your json data into some data structures after you download and parse it.Then you can use them in getView.
3. In this case , you should make your Adapter by extending BaseAdapter , It's more easier and  more customisable thats why works great in all situations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

in the **getView()** method

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId,null);
```